# Can Visual Studio track signature changes like Eclipse does

Tags: visual-studio, method-signature

Imagine I have two C# files.

The first file, Class1.cs contains

```
namespace CrossReferenceCheckingTest
{
    class Class1
    {
        public int doSomething(String s)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

and then in Class2.cs

```
namespace CrossReferenceCheckingTest
{
    class Class2
    {
        public void callDoSomething()
        {
            Class1 c1 = new Class1();

            int x = c1.doSomething("asdf");
        }
    }
}
```

If I change the signature of `Class1::doSomething` (eg: `public String doSomething(int i){}`) I will break the code in Class2.cs.

When I'm cutting Java code, the Eclipse editor will underline packages/classes with a red squiggle.

Is there a way in Visual Studio to see if any files in the project/solution are using the old broken signature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio (2010, at least) will immediately note the breaking change you posit above, underlining the relevant code in `Class2` in red, and noting the error in the error list.

If you don't see this underlining, make sure the relevant switches are enabled in Visual Studio's options (VS 2010 again), under *Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced*:

- Underline errors in the editor
- Show live semantic errors

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, but that appears to only work if you have "Class2.cs" open.

Comment: It appears that when you build a project all files in the project are inspected and thus any broken calls will be flagged in the Errors List.  If a solution has two projects and only one project is built, the errors in the second project will not be found, so one has to rebuild the Solution. 

VS doesn't provide the same level of in your face feedback.  Given one has to build all the time, at least it won't go unnoticed.